# Wordpress Redirect for User Role

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I'm using Wordpress with a User Role that should be redirected to `/userrole`  when they try to visit `/`. Can anyone help me out? I tried a few things but it doesn't work.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
function redirect_users_by_role() { 
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
   $role_name = $current_user->roles[0];
   if('specuserrole' === $role_name) { 
      wp_redirect('website.com/userole'; ); } 
   } 
   add_action( '/'', 'redirect_users_by_role' );
```

Comment: And the things you tried were?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are hooking into a WordPress action of `/` which doesn't exist. I'm not sure if you have read about what actions are available to you, but there is a full list [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Based on this, it appears as though you want to hook into an action, check that we are on the front page and then redirect accordingly. With that in mind I would suggest the below:

```
function redirect_users_by_role() { 
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
   $role_name = $current_user->roles[0];
   if('specuserrole' === $role_name && is_page('home')) { 
      wp_redirect('website.com/userole');
      exit(); 
   } 
 } 
add_action('init', 'redirect_users_by_role');
```

We are now hooking into the `init` action as WordPress tells us that we have a fully authenticated user at this point. We then check that the current page is the home page using `is_page('home')` and then do your redirection logic if needed.

It is not tested as I don't have a WordPress installation to hand so let me know if it works.